# How does this Silverlight .xaml page work?

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I'm more or less a Silverlight newbie. I have this page:

http://*mydomain*/*mynamespace??*.SilverlightTestPage.aspx#/Pages/Home.xaml

When I build and run the solution it runs up the start page, however the .xaml file isn't in my solution. How is this working? And what is the 'mynamespace' I'm referring to in the above URL?

Comment: It's probably mapped to a different file. The Routing configuration   is usually located in `MainPage.xaml`.

Comment: It may also be loading "Home.xaml" from a DLL or referenced project.  The only way to know is to follow the startup logic in app.xaml.cs.